# How To Automate a Native OSX Application with VSCode?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

How can I gain programmatic access, with VSCode, to the objects in a native OSX application, written in Swift or Objective-C?

When i say "with VSCode", I mean coding against the object-hierarchy of the target application in the Visual Studio Code IDE, using any language that VSCode supports.

Ideally, consider 2 scenarios:

- Scenario in which I am the author of said native application, so I can prepare it for access by VSCode.
- Scenario in which I am *not* the author of said native application, so I cannot get 'under the hood'.

Could something like this be used?
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/

Note, I wish to gain programmatic access to the underlying object-hierarchy, not just click buttons on the UI.

Comment: @mipadi's answer handles Scenario #1 in the general case. Scenario #2 is a security violation. If you find a way to do it, expect either the author of said application or Apple to do their best to ensure that your way doesn't remain open.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html), if the application supports it. If you wrote the application yourself, you can add [AppleScript support](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_intro/SAppsIntro.html) to it.

Comment: thx for reply, @mipadi. Can you say if AppleScript will provide access to the underlying object-hierarchy? Or just click buttons on the UI?

Comment: @johnywhy: It depends on the application. Developers _can_ give access pretty deeply into the application with AppleScript, but it's up to the developer to expose what they want via AppleScript.

Comment: When you say "use AppleScript", you mean code my automation in AppleScript? I believe VSCode does not support AppleScript. Although, OSX automation now supports javascript, which is available in VSCode. http://developer.telerik.com/featured/apples-biggest-announcement-yet-isnt-phones-watches/  But ideally, i'd like to use any VSCode language to control OSX application objects.

Comment: The scripting support features @mipadi linked to are generic. AppleScript is the "original" client of these features, but when you add scripting support you also get support for other languages that run on the Open Scripting Architecture runtime (like JavaScript in Script Editor), and for other clients using the [Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/) including [Python, Ruby, and native ObjC/Swift](http://macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/scriptingbridge.html).

Comment: @johnywhy: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to write some kind of VS Code plugin to control an application?

Comment: @rickster and mipadi, my goal is to gain programmatic access to the Excel 2013/2016 object hierarchy. Ideally, the full object hierarchy that's available in Excel VBA (which is the complete Excel hierarchy), rather than the new JS API for office (which is limited, and has a different syntax). Ideally, using VB.Net in VSCode. Ideally, with full intellisense (code-completion) of all Excel object members and arguments. I don't mind if i have to make some "glue" or bindings manually. thx!

Comment: i cannot find any documentation for using Scripting Bridge with VSCode (which i added to my OP title for clarity).